# How to add a button inside of the new window in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am simply trying to add a button inside of my newly created window. I tried something like tk.Button(canvas bla bla but it didn't work. It doesn't recognise canvas window. How do we do it?

```
import rsa
from fernet import Fernet
import string
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import base64
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
def new_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(master)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()
HEIGHT = 400
WIDTH = 300





master = tk.Tk()
master.maxsize(1000, 1000)

tk.Button(master, text="new window", bg='black', fg='#469A00',
                              command=lambda: new_window()).grid(row=9,
                                                     column=2,
                                                     sticky=tk.W,
                                                     pady=4,)


tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are issues in your code: 1) `canvas` in first `tk.Button(canvas, ...)` is undefined; 2) `sifrele` function is undefined.  Did you want to create the second button inside the new window actually?

Comment: Solved 2.But 1, why is that so? I repeat the main question. Isn't that how its supposed to work?

Comment: There is no variable named `canvas`. Inside `sifrele()`. `canvas` inside `new_window()` is a local variable, available only inside the function to be used.

Comment: Your question is still not clear.  What is the expected result you want?

Comment: Simply, I want two windows. One button to other window. And a button inside that other window aswell. Just that. Nothing else.

Comment: That could be done so simply. Why are you using two functions.

Comment: okay I removed a few errors again and simplified it more. How can I do it, would you explain?

Comment: You can create button in the new window the same as you create button in the master window.

Comment: @Stayheuh for your code just specify the window as the root . ` btn = tk.Button(window, text='Welcome')
    btn.pack()`